# iPhone 11 erratic airplane mode

Tags: iphone, airplane-mode

My iPhone turns airplane mode on or off randomly. I put AM on at bedtime and get awakened by alerts in the night.Do I have to start my iPhone 11 off to get some sleep?

Answer (score 2):

Switching off communications modes from the lock screen panel is overridden by the OS each night - they wil be back on in the morning, though I'm not certain what time they trigger.

You can avoid this by using Do Not Disturb instead.
Settings > Do Not Disturb. You can set it manually or on a schedule.